# Form Recognizer Tool OCR issues

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

I have been exploring Azure Form Recognizer for one of my project where we wants to perform OCR on some hand written texts.

1. The problem is that when we give scanned images to the tool to process, it some time doesn't even recognize the text written on it (even if it is clearly written). I tried multiple type of images by performing enhancement on it and also the B/W or colored copy of it but it doesn't works.
2. Some times it recognize value of two fields as one and this leads to incorrect data where one field is completely blank and other is having value of other one along with its own.
3. When there is NO VALUE in the tagged field in the testing data, it try to read the from some other place which is not even closer to that field or sometimes un-tagged

Could you please help with these queries.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share also sample forms please make sure data is anonymized and without any real data ? 
Please contact customer service to debug this issue.

Thanks, 
Neta - MSFT